# Discourage "suggest to Apple" or "report to Apple" answers

Tags: discussion

I submit that we should be discouraging answers suggesting reporting issues to Apple. Apple isn't, shall we say,  super interested in addressing reports from users about issues they encounter in cases where there isn't already extensive experience of the same kind, in which case pointing to references about that experience is the appropriate answer.

If the goal of such answers is to suggests ways one might get Apple to act on issues that are new or peculiar or rare, or about which little has been written, perhaps a better substitute would be concrete suggestions about journalists or tech bloggers one might contact who are in a position to place meaningful pressure on Apple, or who have the scope to explore the issue further.

I suggest that we do what we can to encourage the latter (which could be generally helpful) in favor of the former (which can often just seem dismissive or even provocative); or to point to existing references that address the issue where they exist.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "site policy": Do you expect moderators do delete comments/answers proposing reporting an issue to Apple, do you want to have people edit such remarks out of answers, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear: Guidelines, e.g. in help, or even just consensus here (to link to).

Answer (score 4):

To be honest I'm not sure what problem we'd really be trying to solve here?

It's also not clear on what basis you assume: *Apple isn't, shall we say, super interested in addressing reports from users about issues they encounter in cases where there isn't already extensive experience of the same kind* ?

To me it stands to reason that Apple would not have extensive experience on issues with its products if it wasn't due to the feedback of users, so we shouldn't be openly discouraging this.

I deal with Apple regularly and they openly encourage feedback, often referring users to their [Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) page on which it is clearly stated:

> Apple strives to bring the best personal computing experience to students, educators, creative professionals and consumers around the world through its innovative hardware, software and Internet offerings. Apple welcomes your feedback on its products.

So for me, if an answer includes a link and/or suggestion to provide feedback to Apple as part of a broader answer, I don't see a problem.

I **do** think, however,  an answer that offers nothing more than a suggestion to submit feedback to Apple isn't really an answer and, in those cases, when Moderators are made aware of such answers we do have a role to play - perhaps converting such answers to a comment.

And *perhaps* the [How do I write a good answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page could be edited to somehow capture that an answer which is nothing more than a suggestion to provide feedback to Apple is not an answer. But, to be honest, I haven't come across many answers like this, so once again I'm not sure what problem we're trying to solve?

Comment: We'll have to disagree about Apple's sincerity in encouraging feedback; but I expect that's part of the issue here. AskDifferent is a very pro-Apple environment, and really the entirely unhelpful suggestion to "report to Apple" is just a symptom.